# WiringPi Interrupt Problem

Tags: raspbian, gpio, wiringpi, interrupts

I'm trying to get interrupts working on the Raspberry Pi using the wiringPi library.
When using INT_EDGE_RISING the code below results in very few interrupts when operating the button. This is indicated by 3-5 printf's '.'.

But when using INT_EDGE_FALLING the interrupt seems to be called continuously as the code is printing an endless string of '.'. This rather looks like a level interrupt than an edge triggered one.

The GPIO is configured in my software only and the internal pull-up is enabled so I can be sure that it is not floating.

Now the question is why the interrupt is called continuously when pulling the pin to ground. And how do I get the code to call the interrupt only once when an edge is detected?
I very much appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

// pin defines (BCM2835 numbering)
#define BUTTON    17

void myInterrupt (void)
{
    printf("."); fflush (stdout);
}

int main (void)
{
    if (wiringPiSetupGpio () < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to setup wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
        return 1 ;
    }
    else
    {
            pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
            pullUpDnControl(BUTTON, PUD_UP);
    }

    if (wiringPiISR (BUTTON, INT_EDGE_FALLING, &myInterrupt) < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to setup ISR: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: That code works properly on my B+.

Comment: What do you have connected to the pin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WiringPi: Random Interrupts caused by PWM?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23802/wiringpi-random-interrupts-caused-by-pwm)

Comment: The input pin is directly connected to either 3V3 or GND via a jumper wire.

Comment: I'm afraid the most likely explanation is you have the wire attached to the wrong pin.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is as follows:

I've changed the power supply which is rated 1500 mA to a different one and the glitches now are gone.

Thanks for all your input.